# Knockout toJSON function doesn't create proper JSON with an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, knockout.js

Using knockout to create a JSON string from an observable array, but the output is not what is expected.  It's including an index # in the output.  Take a look at the following simplified example:

I have an array called "selectedFileTypes" with two items.  When I convert that array to an Observable Array, then call toJSON using the following:

```
ko.toJSON(ko.observableArray(selectedFileTypes))
```

The output is

```
{"0":{"DescriptionWithExtension":"Images (*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.bmp;*.png)","Extension":"*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.bmp;*.png"},"1":{"DescriptionWithExtension":"Documents (*.doc;*.docx;*.txt;*.pdf)","Extension":"*.doc;*.docx;*.txt;*.pdf"}}
```

However, when I call this:

```
ko.toJSON(ko.observableArray([{name:"abc",num:"123"},{name:"def",num:"345"}]))
```

The output is:

```
[{"name":"abc","num":"123"},{"name":"def","num":"345"}]
```

[image]

Comment: I am trying to understand, is the structure of selectedFileTypes different from the {name:"abc",num:"123"},{name:"def",num:"345"} structure? If yes, then what are you asking? I am also not sure why you are serializing the observable array like this.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/L1wcwbcs/

Comment: `toJSON` converts your data to  a `JSON string`.`toJS` converts it to a `plain JavaScript object`. https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/40/. not sure how you get an object.

Comment: Try `JSON.stringify(selectedFileTypes)`

Comment: Which version of knockout do you use? Cannot reproduce on latest version. Could you show affected example on jsfiddle?